# Retrieve SQL results, grouped by categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

having a fairly low level in sql, I come to seek your help because I am blocked.

So I have a database containing my 2 tables, an article table and a category table. In my article table, I have a field that contains the IDs of the categories to which it belongs in the JSON format.

Schematically, the categories table looks like this:

```
|    Name    |  id |
|    Cat1    |  1  |
|    Cat2    |  2  |
|    Cat3    |  3  |
```

And the table articles:

```
|     Title     |   id  |       Categories      |
|     Title1    |   1   |         [1,2]         |
|     Title2    |   2   |         [1,3]         |
|     Title3    |   3   |         [2,3]         |
```

Currently, I retrieve my articles as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles a
JOIN categories c
ON JSON_CONTAINS(a.categories, CAST(c.id AS CHAR))
```

Then in php I group them by categories. But I find that this solution is not very clean.

So I wanted to know if a SQL query could retrieve a list of articles already grouped by categories in this way:

Cat1
- Article 1
- Article 2

cat2
- Article 1
- Article 3

Cat3
- Article 2
- Article 3

Comment: you should not use comma separated  values in columns  .. you should normalize the related  data

Comment: Hello, you're absolutely right, I'll put an intermediate table between my two tables to avoid commas.

Comment: then  post  the corretct data struc  so  is possible answer  properly at your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better database design to make a new table `ArticleCategories` that lists each articles categories:

`ArticleID, CatID`

Where an ArticleID can have multiple CatID...

Now you can associate multiple categories to one article and easily search this new database with SQL for correlations between categories and articles.

```
SELECT    c.category, STRING_AGG(a.title, ',')
FROM      articles a
LEFT JOIN articleCategories ac
       ON a.id = ac.articleID
LEFT JOIN categories c
       ON c.id = ac.categoryID
GROUP BY  c.category
```

Comment: This is how a lot of people solve this issue. There are of course other ways, but this is simple and effective.

Comment: I make the modifications, then I come back to you, thank you for your answer!